# Ruby version 1.9.3 becomes 'un boot strapped'

Tags: ruby, bootstrapping

It has been working fine, and then suddenly it thinks it is version 1.8.7 (the ruby that came with snow leopard), not 1.9.3 (the one running on rvm, and the one called in the shebang line.

It happened last night, the problem went away, and now it's back again. I have removed the stap line from my bash profile, quit terminal, put it back, quit terminal, restarted my machine. I am vexed I must admit.

Script:

```
#!/Users/ben/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p0
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Return: `1.8.7`

Irb using rvm:

```
Using /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
1.9.3p0 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.3" 
1.9.3p0 :002 >
```

It has been working fine, and then suddenly stopped, my .bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Comment: What are using for your shebang?

Comment: I will edit my question to show

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't run your script using `ruby` itself rather than using a shebang?

Comment: well to run the script I type `ruby scriptname.rb`

Comment: `ruby filename.rb` from terminal still gives me 1.8.7... ```ruby filename.rb``` from irb 1.9.3 gives me `1.9.3p0 :002 > `ruby test.rb`
 => "1.9.3\n" `

Comment: Woah, you're saying `ruby --version` is 1.8.7 even though you've done `rvm use 1.9.3`? And if you're using `ruby` to execute the script the shebang is ignored.

Comment: Haha, OK... so I have just noticed something... I had not explicitly typed in `rvm use 1.9.3` ... I had made an alias in my .bash_profile that is `alias iruby='rvm use 1.9.3; irb'`, so as I had opened irb in 1.9.3 I was presuming that ruby was set throughout. It seems not... but I have had this alias for a while, so I'm not quite sure why it suddenly happened - or if this was the reason. but it does now give me 1.9.3 at least. I'm just confused as to why it is fine for a day and then suddenly goes a bit funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would update your scripts to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

As the "shebang" so it simply grabs the current `ruby` command. This will enable you to `rvm use ...` whatever you like and the scripts don't need to be changed.

Comment: I have seen lots of examples using this... as I didn't know what env was, I didn't use it - just read up about it... makes sense (can I do the same with bash scripts? or is there no need for that?

Comment: You should not be doing this for bash scripts. `/bin/bash` is no less reliable than `/usr/bin/env`. You only want to use this trick when you're not certain where things will be.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have a .rvmrc file lying around somewhere that's switching you back to your system ruby. Take a look through the directories you are navigating through and see if you can find one.